# Discord oAuth2 API ratelimit triggered without any (known) cause

Tags: php, discord

First question! Woho!

I'm currently coding a Dashboard for a Discord bot in PHP.
Recently, when trying to select a server, it would only display 3 malfunctioning items. So I checked the complete array using `print_r()` and it turned out it rate-limited me.

Now, I got no idea why that happened, as I'm the only person on the server. So what am I doing wrong? Here is the code for listing the selection page:

```php
$all = DiscordAPI("/users/@me/guilds");
foreach ($all as $guild) {
    echo "<a href='/?server=" . $guild['id'] . "'><p>";
        if ($guild['icon']) {
            if (substr($guild['icon'], 0, 2) == "a_") {
                echo "<img class='server-icon' src='https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/" . $guild['id'] . "/" . $guild['icon'] . ".gif?size=64'>";
            } else {
                echo "<img class='server-icon' src='https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/" . $guild['id'] . "/" . $guild['icon'] . ".webp?size=64'>";
            }
        } else {
            $words = explode(" ", $guild['name']);
            $acronym = "";

            foreach ($words as $w) {
                $acronym .= $w[0];
            }
            echo "<img class='server-icon' src='https://cdn.statically.io/avatar/s=64/" . $acronym . "'>";
        }
    echo $guild['name'];
    echo "</p></a>";
}
```

And here is the code for the `DiscordAPI()` function:

```php
function DiscordAPI($endpoint)
{
    if (!$_SESSION['token']) {
        die("No token provided");
    }
    $ch = curl_init("https://discord.com/api" . $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $_SESSION['token']
    ));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($data, true);
}
```

There are 2 API calls before this code to verify that there is a valid token.

---

Quick sidenote: I got Autism, so I might understand stuff a bit differently. Don't be scared to ask if I worded something hard to understand. Thank you for trying to understand me.